# Plotting equation in Matlab using for loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot an equation using a for-loop. I have tried several different ways, but keep getting the apparently common error "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals". The equation I want to plot is *y(x) = (x^4)-(4*x^3)-(6*x^2)+15*.

The last code I tried was the following:

```
y(0) = 15;
for x = [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
    y(x) = (x^4)-(4*x^3)-(6*x^2)+15;
end
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Matlab. The error you got is not specific to the way of calculation, but the language syntax itself.

Answer (score 2):

To start from the beginning,

```
y(0) = 15;
```

will give you the following error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

This is because Matlab's indexing starts at 1. Other languages like C and Python start at 0.

---

Matlab can work directly with vectors. So in your code, there is no need for a loop at all.
You can do it like this:

```
x = [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6];
y = (x.^4) - (4*x.^3) - (6*x.^2) + 15;
plot(x, y);
```

Note that we need to use element-wise operators like `.*` and `.^` to calculate the values vectorized for every element. Therefore a point `.` is written in front of the operator.

---

Additionally, we can improve the code substantially by using the [colon operator](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to generate `x`:

```
x = -3:6; % produces the same as [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6]
y = (x.^4) - (4*x.^3) - (6*x.^2) + 15;
plot(x, y);
```

If you want finer details for your graph, use [`linspace`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) as suggested by @Yvon:

```
x = linspace(-3, 6, 100); % produces a vector with 100 points between -3 and 6.
y = x.^4-4*x.^3-6*x.^2+15;
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: It would be good to include why the error occurred and what the OP should do to avoid it next time. We need to make the users *understand what they are doing wrong*, not only present a working solution. For example: Why `y(x)` does not work. Perhaps introducing the `:` operator to generate the `x` values directly with `x = -3:6` would be helpful, too.

Comment: @Matt great feedback! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = linspace(-3, 6, 100);
y = x.^4-4*x.^3-6*x.^2+15;
plot(x,y)
```